# ndb query returns old property value

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have encountered  a strange case in the App Engine production environment.

There was an entity which was updated properly. I was able to see the updated value in the Datastore viewer. There was also a request, which retrieved the same entity in a query. Entity appeared in the result, but it had the old value of the property. I was able to fix the issue by clearing a memcache.
The query was performed directly on datastore, not returned from memcache. Cursor is initialized to None

```
announcements, cursor, more = query.fetch_page(
    msg.valid_data.get('limit') or 40, start_cursor=cursor)
```

Are there any cases when a direct query can return results from memcache?
There is nothing about it in [ndb caching documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/cache)

Could it be related to cursors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not related to memcache or cursors, but with eventual consistency. A non-ancestor query is explicitly not guaranteed to return updated data.

See the documentation on [structuring data for strong consistency](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency).

Comment: I thought that eventual consistency can only affect which entities appear in the result, not their content

Comment: No, not at all. If you make a change to an existing entity, then do a query, it is quite possible to get back the old version of that entity.